# I am feeling well, though not feeling well but feeling good

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I was thinking about sentences like:

**It sounds good**

**It sounds well**

I didn't see a difference and couldn't understand why **"good"** was used more often than **"well"** and I found some interesting example...

**I feel good** - It means right now it's comfortable for me

If I will say:

**I feel well** - It will be that my body is healthy now and I am feeling healthy

But what if I want to make the analogy with:

**It sounds well**

Like, that it works without any errors, problems, noises. The process of sounding is clear and flawless.

A person may have had any operation and is being asked now how he is feeling his new hand. He is anwering:

**I am feeling well** - the process of me feeling my new hand works perfect

It would be funny if to combine all of them:

**1) I can feel my hand perfectly**

**2) though I am not healthy**

**3) but it's not comfortable for me**

A: How is your hand?

B:I am feeling well, though not feeling well but feeling good

I know that **"I am feeling well"** should be **"I am feeling it well"** but it would have been amusing.

Am I right about all of it?

Answer (score 2):

*I am feeling it well* should only be used if you're trying to talk about exploring something by touch. To *feel something well* would mean to thorough feel it, in the more *active* sense of feeling, rather than the purely perceptive sense of feeling.

If there is a question of whether someone *has feeling in* their hand, we wouldn't use *I am feeling it*, unless they were using their other hand to explore it by touch. They would say *I can feel it*, or *I have feeling in it*. In neither case would they apply *well* as an adverb to that usage of *feel*. They might say *I can feel it vividly*, or *I have good feeling in it* (not *a good feeling*, which would mean something else).

Used more generally, *well* is used as an adverb for doing things to a reasonable standard. That is not its use with *feel*, as *feel* is a linking verb - and *well* is **functioning as an adjective**. So a person can say *I can hear you well*, and it means they can hear you clearly. *This knife cuts well* means the knife is good at cutting things. In that usage, *well* is **functioning as an adverb**. So, let us consider:

> She **sounds well**

This is the *feel well* sense of *well*, an adjective as complement to a linking verb. You can also say:

> She **sounds good**

*Sounds* is still a linking verb here, and *good* is (as usual) an adjective.

> She **hears well**

This is the *adverb* sense of *well*, where it is modifying a verb being used intransitively. We know it's an adverb because *hear* is not a linking verb.

> She **hears good**

This is non-standard grammar, but nonetheless common in some dialects where *good* is used as an adverb broadly equivalent to *well*. I wouldn't emulate it, but you should be prepared to come across it, like "I don't hear that good, I'm afraid" if someone is hard of hearing and apologetic about it.

However, there are verbs that can be linking verbs, but can also be action verbs. In those cases, you have to be more careful. Consider:

> You **sound your horn**.

This means to use the horn to produce sound. Then you can have:

> You sound your horn **well**.

It's obvious here that the object of *sound* is *your horn*, and *well* is an adverb - because you know that sound is an action verb because it has an object. But then you might have:

> Suddenly, a **horn sounded**

Here, the horn is the **object** of the verb *to sound*. If *well* were to be used here, it would still be an adverb, though there are complements that might be used with *sound* as a linking verb, transforming the meaning.

> The horn **sounded broken**

The horn sounds as if it is broken.

Basically, you need to work out whether you need an adverb or adjective when composing, and whether you're reading an adverb or adjective when you are reading. Some words can be used as both, which can create ambiguity. If there's ambiguity, go for the meaning which seems least weird as an assumption.

> A horn sounded well beyond the city wall

Now, ideally there would be a comma here. Did the horn sound well, beyond the city wall, or did it sound, well beyond the city wall? However, the comma is not essential, and which meaning is intended will usually be the one that is most sensible - the horn cannot be healthy or unhealthy in normal discourse, so it is clearly sounding well beyond the city wall - an action verb - rather than being a less defined distance away and sounding well - a linking verb.

Answer (score 0):

"I am feeling" is a redundant and improper form, what about "good" as an adverb...lol! Why people try to change the grammar rules of the English language? To confuse us even more?

What do you earn when you change "I feel" to I am feeling? Just nothing. "I feel" itself means "I feel at the moment". Then why to change it giving it progressive form?

If it comes to "good" used as an adverb, well....do you know what happens? Ignorants all over the world are too many to overcome. It is not clear to them what an adverb and an adjective is so they try to change it to sound "proper" in all cases? Funny! We have 2 words to use as adverbs "well" and "fine" and we have "good" as adjective. I knew it...some day ignorants will change the beautiful language. How sad.

Comment: Would you please re-paragraph you answer, like others. That would make your answer easier to read.